# SharePoint Central Administration Login

Tags: sharepoint

I am reading several articles that tell me to 'log into Central Administration as Admin' but I do not know how to do that. I am a Farm Admin but when I logout of Central Admin it just wants to close the window so I cant switch accounts. I have the main account for this dev SP.

Answer (score 0):

Our Administrator changed my account and I was then able to solve my core issue was not being able to create a new BDC.
He added me to Local Admin Account

Comment: Check to make sure you have edit/execute and read permissions on the BDC Service Application,  you shouldn't need to be given local admin account access to create a BDC.